# Why won't my player's Rigidbody2D get moved by my Conveyer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that takes the rigidbody of anything colliding with it and moving it using MovePosition. The script works for my Plate object but it isn't working for my player.

Here is the Script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ConveyerBelt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 Direction;
    public float moveSpeed;

    bool colliding;
    Collider2D OtherCollider;
    Rigidbody2D OtherRB;


    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(OtherCollider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
        {
            OtherRB = OtherCollider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }

        if (colliding)
        {
            OtherRB.MovePosition(OtherRB.position + (Direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
            print("ConveyerBelting");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        colliding = true;
        OtherCollider = collision;
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        colliding = false;
    }

}
```

Here's what my plate contains:
[Image of plate's Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCf6K.png)

And here's what my player contains:
[Image of Player's Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZlRF.png)

If anyone needs anymore info please request it. I'll be willing to show whatever it is I need to to get this fixed
If I'm an idiot just help me before you tell me

I've tried using different ways of movement(using the transform) and detecting collision(OnTriggerStay2D) but those didn't work. I was expecting the rigidbody to be moved and it did not☹

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this can help, but I want to point out on one obvious problem of this script: it breaks if more then one objects with collider at a time enters the  ConveyerBelt trigger zone.
Look: when any object wiht Collider enters Conveyer, You lose reference (OtherCollider) to first Collider. And if this object have Rigidbody2D, then you lose reference (OtherRB) to first Rigidbody2D, and first object stops moving.
And worst part of this issue - if any collider leaves Conveyer, than OtherRB stop's moving.

You may want to have a List with all Rigidbody2D entering trigger zone, and use Your MovePosition method, if this List is not empty, on each item in List (with foreach loop). Maybe this could be somehow helpful.
For example, You could implemet it like this:

```
private List<Rigidbody2D> rbOnConveyerList = new List<Rigidbody2D>();

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.TryGetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(out Rigidbody2D rBody))
        rbOnConveyerList.Add(rBody);
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.TryGetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(out Rigidbody2D rBody))
        rbOnConveyerList.Remove(rBody);
}

void Update()
{
    if (rbOnConveyerList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Rigidbody2D rBody in rbOnConveyerList) {
            rBody.MovePosition(rBody.position + (Direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
        }
        print("ConveyerBelting");
    }
}
```